# What is the name for concatenated infinitive + reflexive pronoun combinations like "levantarse" and "quedarnos"

Tags: terminología

I'm interested in reading more about this grammatical phenomenon and its rules but I don't know what to call it. Is it considered a tense, or does it have a different term? There's no corresponding phenomenon in French or English, e.g. no "tohaveus" or "avoirnous", so I haven't encountered it before.

Comment: levantarse [stand or stand up] and quedarse [[remain or stay in a place] are called reflexive verbs. In Spanish they say: verbos pronominales. In French there is the same thing: se laver [les mains], s'asseoir [to sit down] etc. In French, they are called les verbes pronominaux. In English, we use reflexive pronouns to lift ambiguity: The cat was licking **itself**. For the Spanish and French, you just have to memorize the uses. They are not tenses, they are a "form". In Spanish, you have to add the pronouns based on the person: Nos levantamos temprano. =We wake up early.

Comment: In French, these are conjugated too: Nous nous lavons les mains trois fois par jour. Perhaps you go look these up: verbos pronominales, verbes pronominaux.

Answer (score 2):

A verb that requires a reflexive pronoun is called a **[verbo pronominal](https://dle.rae.es/verbo#5TVOxkC)**. This pronoun is attached at the end of the verb in the infinitive, gerund and (affirmative) imperative tenses, but appears before the verb and separate from it in other tenses<sup>1</sup>:

- Vamos a **cansarnos** mucho.
- Está **duchándose**.
- ¡**Cállate**!
- **Se cayó** al suelo.
- No **te rindas**.

A pronoun that is attached at the end of a verb is called a **[pronombre enclítico](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Pronombre_encl%C3%ADtico)**. This may be a reflexive pronoun (that refers to the subject), but it may also be a pronoun that refers to an object different from the subject:

- No quiere **moverse** de allí (*reflexive enclitic pronoun*).
- No necesito mi bicicleta antigua. Voy a **venderla** en eBay (*non-reflexive enclitic pronoun "la", that refers to the feminine object "la bicicleta"*).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>In old literary texts, personal tenses with attached enclitic pronouns such as the famous "**Érase** una vez" or "**díjole**" are common. This is not common anymore.</sub>